# Can someone help me with contextual filters in profile2

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, users

I would like to single out a second profile with a views page using basic taxonomy reference or user information. Can you help me get my contextual filter to work with either user id, profile id, or taxonomy reference. I have my view to show users of a particular roll type. All users of this type will have a unique taxonomy reference ( or tag). When I choose fields for this tag in contextual filters and test it using the tag I don't get any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to (finally) populate something on the user id. I guess it's the best way because I am going to be using rules to handle the information after the profile is created. Unfortunately, for some reason when I create a new user sometimes one of my profile id's is set to '0' *shrugs* which throws off the population of the field (check this especially if you use profile2_regpath).

How I was able to do it was to like this

[image: screen shot of relations and arguments]

I referenced the profile based on user id... then I drew three relationships on the profile, the profile type, and the user id.  I finally chose fields that substantiate the information I needed the user to see (in this case they are just testing it out). Please let me know if there is another way. I'm assuming there has to be something else out there or something I am missing. It populates one user at a time based on the profile owner's user id.